# Touch events aren't detected in Libgdx after redrawing?

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, touch, stage

I'm drawing a menu on the Game Screen when pause button is clicked, on this menu i'm drawing a play button. But the problem is that once i press the play button the touch events on the game screen are not detected!
here's the code snippet

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

//some code here

public void render(float delta) {
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();
if(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.isMenuOn,false)){

menu.draw(batch, menu.getX(), menu.getY(), Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
playBtn.draw(....);

}
if(playBtn.isTouched()){
prefs.putBoolean(Constants.isMenuOn, true);

prefs.flush();

}
......
...
batch.end();
}


}
```

Comment: You're doing far too much in your render method. This should only draw what you want on the screen. I'd suggest refactoring the code and moving the isTouched, the pref update and whatever ....... does outside of the render. That will hopefully help you determine what is going wrong (I can't tell, btw, what exactly is wrong - there is far too much noise in the render call, which executes about 60 times a second, btw).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i used camera.unproject(touchX, touchY); and it worked well for me